# Self-Closing Tag Issue with document.innerHTML in Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, tags, innerhtml

I am writing a browser plug-in for Firefox(Greasemonkey), Opera and Chrome in Javascript for a website. The issue is, when I load the `document.innerHTML` into a variable,

```
<form name="foo" action="foo.php" method="get">
<td id="td">text:
<input name="k" type="text" />
&nbsp;</td>
</form>
```

... the original code above of the website(which I am writing the plug-in for) is converted into

```
<form name="foo" action="foo.php" method="get">
<td id="td">text:
**<input name="k" type="text">**
&nbsp;</td>
```

... this one. As you can see, the self-closing `<input />` tag is not closed anymore, and the `</form>` tag also disappeared. I have googled almost all the internet but none of the solutions I read did not solve my problem.

Comment: As far as I know, there isn't a way to get the original page source in this way (or at least a way guaranteed to work). The browser will give you a HTML serialisation of a DOM Element's contents when you ask for innerHTML. Loading the page via an XMLHTTPRequest would work, though that's probably not what you're after.

Comment: Why is it an issue? How the browser chooses to represent the elements as HTML markup shouldn't really affect anything. The nature of an `<input>` element is that it doesn't have descendants. The lack of a `/>` doesn't change that.

Comment: The `<input>` tag does not have to be closed in HTML, and in fact in HTML self-closing tags are syntactically incorrect anyway.

Comment: Actually the issue is that because </form> disappears, when I type something in the input and press enter the form does not work properly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The closing `</form>` tags show up for me in Firefox when getting `.innerHTML`.

I'd suggest that the missing tag is due to your markup which I'm pretty sure is invalid:

```
  <!-- A <form> wrapping a <td> ? -->
<form name="foo" action="foo.php" method="get">
    <td id="td">text:
        <input name="k" type="text" />
        &nbsp;
    </td>
</form>
```

The parent of a `<td>` element should be a `<tr>`, not a `<form>`.

Given this markup:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <form name="foo" action="foo.php" method="get">
            <td id="td">text:
                <input name="k" type="text" />
                &nbsp;
            </td>
        </form>
    </tr>
</table>
```

...Firefox gives me this `innerHTML` for the `<table>`:

```
<tbody>
    <tr>
        <form name="foo" action="foo.php" method="get"></form>
            <td id="td">text:
                <input name="k" type="text">
                &nbsp;
            </td>

    </tr>
</tbody>
```

It attempts a correction of the invalid markup.

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/grM4c/

Comment: I pasted the code partially in my first post and of course there is a `<tr>` above. But as I understand from your message there always must be a `<tr>` before putting a `<td>`, right? And also as I mentioned above I am writing a third-party plugin for the website and I am not the admin, so I cannot change the original code. I am trying to find a way in javascript to do this.

Comment: OK, take a look at this, http://jsfiddle.net/UQ4jj/
Both Opera and Firefox gives the same output. By the way, the HTML part is the very original code of the website(except for the table tags in the beggining and in the end, I kept them for the javascript part), unlike the code in my first post.

Comment: @Nail: Yes, same issue. The markup is invalid. You can never rely on invalid HTML markup. If the site has `<table><form><td>`, then the site is coded improperly and needs to be fixed by the admin. Even if you somehow find a JavaScript solution that works with the current rendering, Firefox could change the way it renders invalid markup with its next release, causing your original fix to fail.

Comment: Thank you very much anyway, BTW I am trying to fix the issue by the ugly methods, which is changing the content of innerHTML with replace(). I am going to add the required `</form>` tag myself.

Response for your edit: Yes you are right, but at the moment there is no other way to solve this issue since I cannot reach the admin, if Firefox changes the render it means that I will change my Javascript code too.

Answer (score 0):

Well, taking a look on your code, you care creating a form with a unclosed TD in the middle.

```
<form name="foo" action="foo.php" method="get">
<td id="td"><span>text:<input name="k" type="text" /></span></td>
</form>
```

Try this way.

Comment: The `<td>` in the question's code _does_ have a corresponding closing tag. It should be a child of a `<tr>` rather than a `<form>`, but it _is_ closed.

Comment: Yes @nnnnnn is right, and also I am writing a third-party extension for the website which I am not the admin. Because of this I cannot change the html part, so it means I have to find a solution in Javascript.

Comment: right @nnnnn, I saw something wrong but I fail writing the code.