# innerHtml changing behavior of self closing tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui, dom

**Sorry for repeated question but existing questions not helpful.**

I an working on XSLT code show in visible format, I have predefined XSLT code on server side I take that code and show into textarea firstly and then processed.

Here is my code which is in textarea

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:atlantis="urn:atlantis">
  <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration = "yes" />
  <xsl:param name="DOCUMENT_BASEURL"/>
  <xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:value-of select="something" />
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

I take take taxtarea code and assign it to the dom as following

```
var xslt = $('#dummy').val();
var el = document.createElement( 'body' );
el.innerHTML = xslt;
```

**Now my question is after assigning data to dom, when I checked innerHTML data it's changing behavior of auto closing tags(xsl:output,xsl:param,xsl:value-of etc).**

Here is my innerHTML output

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:atlantis="urn:atlantis">
  <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes">
  <xsl:param name="DOCUMENT_BASEURL">
  <xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:value-of select="something")">
  </xsl:value-of></xsl:template>
</xsl:param></xsl:output></xsl:stylesheet>
```

I refer following links but did't get any solution from that

[Self-Closing Tag Issue with document.innerHTML in Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7409393/self-closing-tag-issue-with-document-innerhtml-in-javascript)

[Javascript - .innerHTML changes auto close tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26728671/javascript-innerhtml-changes-auto-close-tags)

**I checked this code on google chrome, firefox and IE11 same thing happens on every browser.**

Please help me out from this stuff.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: @xxxmatko  I read all xslt attribute, functions and loops and shown into visible format ( like C.K editor) and I did that but after changing attributes, functions dynamically  from visible editor I need to update main xslt code which is in textarea. I am able to show updated code in text area but innerHTML not working properly with self closing tag

Comment: And you can not use textarea to show it?

Comment: Have you actually loaded the document with a XML mime type, i.e. is it an instance of `XMLDocument` and not a `HTMLDocument`?